# ARIMA prediction in python

Tags: python, time-series

I have a time-series forecasting problem that I am using the statsmodels python package, I applied the ARIMA MODEL, In python  sm.tsa.ARIMA(data, (p,1,q)) usually transform the data to the first different, for example if we have  a raw data (y1,y2,y3,y4....), first thing ARIMA Find the first difference,(y1-y2,y2-y3,....), so it make the model from this new data (first difference data). my question when I found the model

```
arma_mod1=sm.tsa.ARIMA(firstdifference, (p,1,q))
```

I can predict the first difference data as follow

```
predict_oil =arma_mod11.predict('1980', '2026').
```

MY QUESTION: How can I predict the future raw data ( the main data not the first difference data) using Arima?

Thanks

Comment: The opposite of differencing is `cumsum`, `np.cumsum(predict_oil)`. However, I don't know if statsmodels has any built-in support for this.

Answer (score 3):

The predict method takes an optional parameter named **typ** which lets you decide whether to have predictions in the original time series or in the differenced one.

You should use

```
predict_oil =arma_mod11.predict('1980', '2026', typ='levels')
```

I don't think this will be still helpful for you, but maybe it will be for others.